# AndEngine AnimatedSprite Animate only first sprite

Tags: java, android, animation, sprite, andengine

Why when I am add the new enemy, that don't animate? Animated only first enemy..

```
private BitmapTextureAtlas EnemyTextureAtlas;
private TiledTextureRegion enemyTextureRegion;

EnemyTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);        
enemyTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(EnemyTextureAtlas, this, "enemy.png", 400, 0, 2, 2);

private void addEnemy(final float pX, final float pY)
{
    final AnimatedSprite enemy;
    enemy = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.enemyTextureRegion);
    enemy.animate(200);
    scene.attachChild(enemy);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone textureRegion

```
enemy = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.enemyTextureRegion.clone());
```

Comment: Thanks but with this I have 2 errors: `The constructor AnimatedSprite(float, float, Object) is undefined`
`The method clone() from the type Object is not visible Main.java`

Comment: Ok, I am release my clone function in TiledTextureRegion, it's work now.
Thank you so much

Comment: the method clone() is depreciated , use deepCopy() instead

Answer (score 3):

`enemy = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.enemyTextureRegion.deepCopy());`

instead of

`enemy = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.enemyTextureRegion.clone());`